# prevent previously defined events on mousedown for right-click only

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault, mousedown

I have a soundboard with buttons that trigger AJAX posts on mousedown.

The ideal functionality is to play an audio on left-mousedown and cancel playback on right-mousedown.

The code I have so far disables the context menu and cancels the playback...however, if they are over a button when they right-click (that triggers other previously defined events), it will still honor the mousedown and play that audio.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  document.oncontextmenu = function() {return false;};
  $(document).mousedown(function(e){ 
    if( e.which == 3 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        Cancel_Playback();
      return false; 
    } 
    return true; 
  }); 
});
```

I am trying to disable the right-mousedown from triggering the previously defined events but honor the Cancel_Playback.  Any ideas?

**EDIT**
Updated Title and Description to more accurately reflect what I am trying to accomplish.  This should also help:  http://jsfiddle.net/g9sh1dme/15/

Comment: are you sure 3 is the right button?

Comment: Yeah, with this current code, the Cancel_Playback executes on right-click so.. I believe if you use e.button, the right-click would be 2.. but with e.which, it is 3.

Comment: What exactly does these buttons do? In other words, what are you trying to prevent, do they submit a form, or do they have other javascript event handlers attached to them that you're trying to prevent ?

Comment: They execute another function: Play_Sound(SoundFile) - that is what I would like to prevent.

Comment: Actually, depending on the button, there are other functions it may execute.  However, it is mostly the playback function that I want to disable.

Comment: The name is `preventDefault`, it prevents the default action, you can't prevent other javascript functions from running by adding more event handlers

Comment: I guess I was hoping it would prevent what it would otherwise do but then do the function i specified :) But I see what you are saying.. that wouldn't make any sense.  Is there a line there that I could use to say "don't do this but do this instead"?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v6ywg1hL/1/ cant right click and function fires, whats not working?

Comment: Actually, what I am trying to prevent are other previously defined events that trigger on mousedown.  Ideally, everything except the Cancel_Playback would trigger on a left-button mousedown and only the Cancel_Playback would trigger on the right-button mousedown.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g9sh1dme/15/ - I adjusted that a little to show what I am trying to accomplish....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[stopImmediatePropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/) is probably the function you're looking for.

It cancels all other events **bound to the the same element** and any other delegates higher in the DOM. Order also matters as events are called in the order in which they were bound. You can only cancel events that were bound after the event doing the canceling.

I'm not sure if these changes maintain the validity of your program, but it demonstrates the function's use. Otherwise, I'd just check for right-mousedown in `Play_Sound` and exit out instead of banking on another event to cancel its execution.

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g9sh1dme/17/)**</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  document.oncontextmenu = function() {return false;};
  //For this to work you must bind to the same object or you must bind to something lower in the DOM.
  $(".sound").mousedown(function(e){ 
    if( event.which == 3 ) {
        Cancel_Playback();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return false; 
    } 
    return true; 
  }).mousedown(Play_Sound);
})

function Cancel_Playback() {
    alert("This is all that should be displayed on right-mousedown")
}

function Play_Sound() {
    alert("Display this on left-mousedown... but not on right-mousedown")
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly in the demo!  I attempted to adapt this to my own code but could not quite make it work.  My code is a little more complex than the example, I guess... I am sure if I was a little better at this, it would work.  I did, however, get it to work by `if( event.which == 1 )` to the event for Play_Sound.   Appreciate the answer tho!